# ajax call fires twice in IE compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is a snippet of code I am working with:

```
 var $container = $('#myNumRows');  
$container.scroll(function () {
   if ($container.scrollTop() == 0) {
    addRows('Top'); 
   } else if ($container.innerHeight() + $container.scrollTop() >= $container[0].scrollHeight ) {
     addRows('Bottom');
   }
```

`addRows` is a function with a parameter to note "Top" or "Bottom".

In IE compatibility mode, it adds the rows twice when scrolling to the bottom.  Doesn't happen if not in compatibility mode, and doesn't happen in any other browser (chrome, firefox).  I have tried using a timeout in various places, and I have tried several iterations using debounce from `underscore.js`, but no matter what I do, when it hits the bottom of the scroll, it fires twice in IE compatibility mode.

Can anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Why run in compatibility mode?

Comment: Compatibility mode is a feature given to the user so they can view a poorly designed or older website without breaking it.  There is no reason anyone would use it on a site that followed proper coding standards.  That being said, check your HTML to verify that it's valid.  No duplicate `id`'s, unclosed containers, etc.

Comment: I wish I could blow away the junk I'm working with, but that isn't an option ... have to work with legacy code, and many or most of the users will be using compatibility mode.

Comment: If your HTML is invalid, then you have to fix it.  There is no magic button that makes broken code work without fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a IE-Compatibility-Mode-Bug.
Best solution from my point of view would be to add a variable which requires another up-scroll before adding any more rows like the following:

```
var $container = $('#myNumRows'), bottom = false, top = false;  
$container.scroll(function () {
if ($container.scrollTop() == 0) {
  if (!top) {
    top = true;
    addRows('Top'); 
  } else {
    top = false;
  }
} else if ($container.innerHeight() + $container.scrollTop() >= $container[0].scrollHeight) {
  if (!bottom) {
    bottom = true;
    addRows('Bottom');
  } else {
    bottom = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar issues in IE before when dynamically creating data in infinite scroll scenarios.  The cause (of the similar issue that I encountered) was that the adding of the additional data caused a horizontal or vertical scrollbar to appear, and this in turn has an effect on the container height and/or width and triggers the scroll event.

If the debounce is not working, then I think the sequence of events is likely:

1. Triggers first time
2. Ajax call happens
3. New DOM is appended, affecting layout.  This triggers the layout condition again, triggering a second time.

If that is the case, then a solution will be to switch off the handling until you are done manipulating the DOM, i.e.

1. Triggers first time.  Continue if `(busy == false)` Set `busy = true;`
2. Ajax call happens
3. New DOM is appended.  Add a call to `setTimeout(function() {busy = false;}, 1)`.  Layout triggers again, but `busy == true` so nothing happens
4. timer triggers, sets `busy = false`